# Asymptotes and Isoclines of ODE Direction Field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, conic-sections

I am provided with the following image of the direction field of $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = y^2 - x^2$:

[image]

Plotted in yellow is the -1-isocline: $-1 = y^2 - x^2$.

The solution states that the lower-right asymptote for this isocline is the line $y = -x - 1$. However, as I understand it, the formula for the asymptote of a hyperbola centered at the origin and with foci on the x-axis is $y = \pm \dfrac{bx}{a}$. Therefore, shouldn't the formula for the lower-right asymptote be $y = -x$?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this for me.

EDIT:

Indeed, even [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E2%20-%20x%5E2%20%3D%20-1) states that the asymptotes are $y = x$ and $y = -x$! So I'm very confused as to whether I'm misunderstanding the solution or the solution is incorrect?

EDIT2:

[image]

Comment: @Moo I have not. I used this MIT applet (https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/18/18.03SC/isoclines.html) to plot the direction field, since I'm attempting the associated problem set. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Moo I've edited the OP with the same graph with solutions plotted. The lower-right asymptote seems to clearly be equal to the lower-right portion of $-1 = y^2 - x^2$, which would be along the lower-right part of the line $y = -x$ (since $-1 = y^2 - x^2$ is a hyperbola)?

Comment: @Moo No. The aforementioned applet will only plot the isoclines $y^2 - x^2 = -3, -2, .. 2, 3$. Is that what sufficient? What is the error I should be looking for?

Comment: @Moo This gets me the same result I had before: The solutions asymptotically converge to the lower-right portion of the hyperbola $y^2 - x^2 = -1$. And since the formula for the asymptote of a hyperbola of the type $y^2 - x^2 = -1$ is $y = \pm \dfrac{bx}{a}$, it stands to reason that the lower-right asymptote is the lower-right portion of the line $y = -x$, not $y = -x - 1$ (as claimed in the solution)? I must be completely misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = y^2 - x^2 \tag 1$$
The -1-isocline is the curve where the curves solutions of $(1)$ have a slope $=-1$.
$$-1 = y^2 - x^2 \tag 2$$
We must no confuse the asymptotes of the curve $(2)$ with the asymptote of the curves solutions of equation $(1)$.

The respective asymptotes are the same only if the slopes are equal, that is $=-1$.

Considering the curve $(2)$ which is an hyperbola, the two asymptotes are $y=x$ and $y=-x$.

The slope of $y=x$ is $+1$ while the slope of the solutions of $(1)$ is $-1$. This means that the curves solutions of $(1)$ tend to be orthogonal to the asymptote $y=x$ of the hyperbola at infinity. Thus the asymptote $y=x$ of the hyperbola is NOT asymptote of the curves solutions of $(1)$. On the contrary, they tends to be orthogonal at infinity.

On the other hand, the slope of $y=-x$ is $-1$ which is the same as the slope of the solutions of $(1)$. The asymptote $y=-x$ of the hyperbola is also asymptote of the curves solutions of $(1)$.

NOTE :  Equation $(1)$ is a Riccati's ODE. It is analytically solvable in terms of Bessel functions. The explicit general solution is complicated.

IN ADDITION :

If we express the asymptotic solution of (1) on the form:
$$y=-x+a_0+\sum_{n=1}\frac{a_n}{x^n}$$
puting it into (1) leads to :
$a_0=0\quad;\quad a_1=\frac{1}{2}\quad;\quad a_2=0 \quad;\quad a_3=\frac{3}{8}\quad;\quad ... $
$$y\simeq -x+\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{3}{8x^3}+...$$
So, $y\simeq -x-1$ is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So if I'm not mistaken, it seems that you're agreeing with me that the correct answer is $y = -x$ and not $y = -x - 1$? Please confirm.

Comment: Yes. See the addition to my first answer.